# Combing Filter Query with Concatenate in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following Query that pulls data from another spreadsheet into a daily run sheet to be issued to our drivers. However we are finding there are too many columns making the print too small to read when asked to fit one page wide.  So I would like to combine a couple of columns in a concatenate.

The current formula is:
=QUERY(
Filter(Jobs_Database,Start_Date=E2,Assigned_To=E1),
"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col20")

This is a picture of the spreadsheet.
[image]

I would like to concatenate/join columns "F to L" using a - or , as a spacer.  Is this possible?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data was like my image below and you wanted to select col `A`, then concatenate `F:L`, then select col `T`...

[image]

Add this to cell `V1`:

`=arrayformula(query({A:E,flatten(query(transpose(IF(F:L<>"",F:L&",",)),"",MAX(IF(A:T<>"",ROW(A:A))))),M:T},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col6,Col14",1))`

You basically take advantage of a quirk in `query` that collapses columns when the query 'header' is a big number `MAX(IF(A:T<>"",ROW(A:A)))`. The separator is shown as a comma in `F:L&","`.

If it works for you, I'll add a detailed breakdown of what's happening.

Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :-)

Comment: Thank you Aresvik.  I didn't know I had received a response.  Does Stakoverflow not send an email when a response is received?

I will have a play with your solution.